# Rewriting a url in iis from a subdomain so letsencrypt will find the challenge key

Tags: iis, rewrite, lets-encrypt

I'm having an issue with the above. Basically, I have a webmail.domain.com that I use IIS to redirect to.

When it's time to renew my certificates though, I have to manually disable the webmail rule, and then run the client. Otherwise it won't renew the certs for the webmail.example.com because it's looking under example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge but it's being redirected to webmail.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge which doesn't exist.

So, I wrote a rule to rewrite the url so that anything looking for /.well-known will be rewritten as https://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/whateverthekeyis.

It appears to rewrite the urls correctly, but, the file isn't being served. Which is where I'm a bit stymied. It serves the challenges fine if I disable the rewrite rule(aside from the webmail one) so I'm not really sure what the issue is. There's a webconfig in the acme-challenge to serve extensionless files, and I also have it setup in iis. The url seems to be correct along with the physical path. But, it's clearly not serving the file.

I get a 404.4 not found error when I try to access the url using the rewrite rule to rewrite and webmail.example.com to just example.com.

The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.

Most likely causes:

```
The file extension for the requested URL does not have a handler configured to process the request on the Web server.
```

Requested URL      https://example.com:443/.well-known/acme-challenge/X2cp9qv-ymePYfNERRjh5n8pmxvlvWxMqZUhyaSL

Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\.well-known\acme-challenge\X2cp9qv-ymePYfNERRjh5n8pmxvlvWxMqZUhyaSL

But, without the rewrite rule, I can access that url from my browser.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Please do not use redirects for the folder containing acme-challenges.

Multiple reasons will prevent Let's Encrypt domain validation over HTTP if you try to redirect requests the way you intend to:

1. You want to validate a specific domain. Redirecting to another one will prevent validation.
2. Redirecting to / enforcing HTTPS will prevent validation. The validation Bot will check over HTTP only.
3. Every redirect will prevent validation. The Bot does not follow redirects.

I recommend the following IIS web.config for the acme-challenge folder, if you have installed the rewrite module. It disables rewrites/redirects for this folder, adds the mimetype for extensionless files and ensures the staticfile handler is used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
     <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/plain" />
     </staticContent>
     <handlers>
         <clear />
         <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" type=""
                 modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule"
                 scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read"
                 allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
     </handlers>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For Servers without rewrite module you can skip the `<rewrite>` section.

Hope this helps. Good Luck!